# How to fetch the Checkbox List inserted values in database back to the checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I build a demo application in which I used a checkbox list to get the hobbies and enter those values in the database as follows:

The ASP code for checkbox list is:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxlsthobbies" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem>cricket</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>football</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>pool</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>basketball</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>rugby</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And the corresponding C# code to enter that value in database is as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        foreach (ListItem item in chkboxlsthobbies.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                str += string.Format("{0}, ", item.Text);
            }
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [CheckboxTable] values('" + str + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        bindgrid();
    }
```

Now I am using a Gridview to bind that table data and display it and in that, I am having a onRowEditing and onRowDeleting event.

The Gridview code is as follows:

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="gvtxtedit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="gvtxtdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hobbies">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="gvlblfirstname" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("Hobbies") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the Gridview bind method is as follows:

```
protected void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [CheckboxTable]", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And now I am completely stuck in this problem generally I am able to fetch the value of any field back to TextBox or a Dropdown list on the form

Example:

```
txtfirstname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString();
```

inside the onRowEditing event to fetch the field value back to the control on the form, which I can do for textbox and dropdown.

The problem is I am not able to figure out that how to fetch the multiple values separated by a "," back to a checkbox list, because there are multiple values, I have been trying this for a long time.

Final problem is that fetch the values in database back to the checkbox list inside the onRowEditing event of GridView.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: Thanks for the share but these are the basic insert update delete operations inside Gridview which are fairly easy, I am looking for the specific problem mentioned above. Thanks anyway.. @VDWWD

Comment: In this Tutorial editing is done inside the Gridview only, want to fetch the values of current row back to the controls on the form which i am by the able to do for all the controls except check box list which has multiple values. @VDWWD

Comment: I found the solution and i have added it .. thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this onRowEditing Gridview function to implement the above functionality i.e: to fetch the checkbox list values saved in database back to the checkbox list on the form inside the onRowEditing event of Gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        chkboxlsthobbies.ClearSelection();

        //Get the ID
        int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[Int32.Parse(e.NewEditIndex.ToString())].Values["ID"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CheckboxTable where ID = '"+id+"'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        // Get the exact column and save it in a string.
        string str = dt.Rows[0]["Hobbies"].ToString();
        string[] strlist = str.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray(); //Split into array and trim it.

        //Finally the main functionality to check the values in checkbox list.
        foreach (string s in strlist)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in chkboxlsthobbies.Items)
            {
                if (item.Value == s)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }

            }


        }
```

Thank You.